# How can I fix the form size in a C# Windows Forms application and not to let user change its size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, size, fixed

How can I fix the form size in a C# Windows Forms application and not to let user change its size?

Comment: Oh I got it By changing FormBorderStyle property of a form....

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it works for you....

Comment: @odiseh I stumbled upon this and I see you still didn't accept an answer. please mask an answer as accepted - I'm sure there is a working solution provided in the answers

Answer (score 84):

Check this:

```
// Define the border style of the form to a dialog box.
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

// Set the MaximizeBox to false to remove the maximize box.
form1.MaximizeBox = false;

// Set the MinimizeBox to false to remove the minimize box.
form1.MinimizeBox = false;

// Set the start position of the form to the center of the screen.
form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

// Display the form as a modal dialog box.
form1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I dont think this stops you from double clicking on the title bar and it full screens

Comment: @Tizz I changed above things through designer, it worked.Double click didnt maximize it. I am using VS-2010

Comment: @Tizz is right, double clicking on the title bar still maximizes the form. I am using VS 2022 community edition.

Answer (score 19):

Try to set

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(140, 480);
this.MaximumSize = new Size(140, 480);
```

Answer (score 12):

Minimal settings to prevent resize events

```
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
form1.MaximizeBox = false;
```

Answer (score 10):

Properties -> FormBorderStyle -> FixedSingle

if you can not find your Properties tool. Go to View -> Properties Window

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this isn't the BEST way, but you could set the `MinimumSize` and `MaximimSize` properties to the same value. That will stop it.

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on the form in the *Design* window, necessary changes can be made in the *Properties* window. To adjust the size of the form, the `Width` and `Height` fields of the `Size` property are changed. In order to keep the size of the form constant, the value `FixedSingle` is assigned to the `FormBorderStyle` property.

[image]

In addition, you should prevent the screen from enlarging by editing the window style; the `MaximizeBox` property must be set to `false`.

[image]

When the form is run as a result of the changes made through the properties window, it remains fixed in size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the *Maximise* property to *False*.

Comment: "the maximise property"? Do you mean "the `MaximizeBox` property"?